# How can I check if a specific JSON value is a close match with a value in a given array? Then replace the JSON value with the array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of wholesalers (example):

```
const wholesalers = [
  "B536 - T QUALITY LTD",
];
```

I have an array of JSON objects (example):

```
{
  'Preferred Wholesaler': 'T-Quality'
}, 
{
  'Preferred Wholesaler': 'T Quality'
},
```

How can I match the preferred wholesaler JSON value to one of the values in the array? Then update the JSON object with the value from the array like so: 'Preferred Wholesaler': 'B536 - T QUALITY LTD'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Ignores the first 7 characters of the wholesaler
// Removes the " LTD" from the end:
var newWholesalers = wholesalers.map(wholesaler => {
  return wholesaler.substring(7).replace(" LTD", "")
});

// JSON Data
var newRecords = data.map(record => {

  record["Preferred Wholesaler"] = record["Preferred Wholesaler"].toUpperCase()

  // Returns true if the preferred wholesaler is in the array
  // false if not
  if (newWholesalers.includes(record["Preferred Wholesaler"])) {
    return {
      ...record,
      ["Preferred Wholesaler"]: 'True'
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...record,
      ["Preferred Wholesaler"]: 'False'
    }
  }
});
```

How can I get the includes() function to return the value it matched with, instead of true/false??

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. If there are no strings, serialization, or deserialization involved, then JSON is not involved either.

Comment: Where does `"TQ01 - T QUALITY LTD"` come from? Please add the expected output to the question

Comment: @adiga my bad, I have corrected to the proper output.

Comment: An "object containing JSON" would be even stranger. That'd be something like `const obj = { prop: '["foo","bar","baz"]' }`. I've seen those occasionally (including in Stack Exchange websockets) but they're really weird and usually indicate data organization problems.

Comment: Can we please focus on the actual question and not be super pedantic definitions. @perry besides the name, is there any other kind of identifiable information for each row? If you have an id field, or something the problem would be trivial. Doing a fuzzy string match isn't going to be super easy and its not guaranteed to give correct or expected results.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag, especially the part in capitals.

Comment: @Brenden No, there are no other fields, It is just an array of individual strings (like shown). It does not have to be a perfect match... This program will just be used to automate a few results. Instead of having to go through each result one-by-one typing them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help you get some direction...

```
const wholesalers = [
  "B536 - T QUALITY LTD",
  "B700 - BEST QUALITY cc",
];

var myObject = [
  {
    'Preferred Wholesaler': 'T-Quality'
  },
  {
    'Preferred Wholesaler': 'T Quality'
  },
]

myObject.forEach(function(item, index) {
  wholesalers.forEach(function(wholesaler, index) {
    if (wholesaler.replace(/-/g, ' ').toLowerCase().includes(item['Preferred Wholesaler'].replace(/-/g, ' ').toLowerCase())) {
      item['Preferred Wholesaler'] = wholesaler
    }
  });
  
});

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: This answer comes very close to working with all possible inputs. I'm sure I can find the near perfect regular expression to match each input. Thank you Muhammad.